# How to refresh MainActivity depending on Preference Settings?

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting data from theMovieDb.com. In settings menu it has option for sorting by most popular or highest rated.After user selects his preference, I want to refresh the main activity automatically. I tried several things but nothing worked for me.

MainActivityFragment.java

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    sendJsonRequest();
}

// To initialize the Image Adapter
public ImageAdapter initializeAdapter() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String sortby = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_key), getString(R.string.pref_default_value));
    if (sortby.equals(getString(R.string.pref_rating))) {
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), sortListRating);
    } else if (!sortby.equals(getString(R.string.pref_rating))) {
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), listMovie);

    }
    return mAdapter;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view_movies);


    final ImageAdapter mFinalAdapter = initializeAdapter();

    gridView.setAdapter(mFinalAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

                                    {
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                                                int position, long id) {
                                            Movie movieSelected = listMovie.get(position);
                                            String movieTitle = movieSelected.getTitle();
                                            String movieThumbnail = movieSelected.getUrlThumbnail();
                                            String movieReleaseDate = movieSelected.getReleaseDate();
                                            String movieOverview = movieSelected.getOverview();
                                            String movieRating = movieSelected.getRating();
                                            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsMovies.class);
                                            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_1, movieThumbnail);
                                            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_2, movieTitle);
                                            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_3, movieReleaseDate);
                                            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_4, movieRating);
                                            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_5, movieOverview);

                                            startActivity(i);
                                        }
                                    }

    );


    return rootView;
}


private void sendJsonRequest() {
    //In the case of theMovieDB it is JSON Object Request
    //Specify several argument in JSON Object Request
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            getRequestUrl(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    parseJsonResponse(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(request);

}

private void parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
    if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    long id = -1;
    String title = Constants.NA;
    String releaseDate = Constants.NA;
    String synopsis = Constants.NA;
    String urlThumbnail = Constants.NA;
    String rating = Constants.NA;
    String popularity = Constants.NA;
    String votecount = Constants.NA;

    try {
        if (response.has(KEY_RESULTS)) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentMovies = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //Get the id of the current movie
                //If statement is used to check whether id is null or not.
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_ID) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_ID)) {
                    id = currentMovies.getLong(KEY_ID);
                }
                //Get the synopsis of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_OVERVIEW) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_OVERVIEW)) {
                    synopsis = currentMovies.getString(KEY_OVERVIEW);
                }
                //Get the title of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_TITLE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_TITLE)) {
                    title = currentMovies.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                }
                //Get the urlThumbnail of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_POSTER_PATH) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_POSTER_PATH)) {
                    urlThumbnail = currentMovies.getString(KEY_POSTER_PATH);
                }
                //Get the release date of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_RELEASE_DATE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_RELEASE_DATE)) {
                    releaseDate = currentMovies.getString(KEY_RELEASE_DATE);
                }
                //Get the rating of current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE)) {
                    rating = currentMovies.getString(KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE);
                }

                //Get the popularity of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_POPULARITY) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_POPULARITY)) {
                    popularity = currentMovies.getString(KEY_POPULARITY);
                }

                //Get the vote_count of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_VOTE_COUNT) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_VOTE_COUNT)) {
                    votecount = currentMovies.getString(KEY_VOTE_COUNT);
                }
                //Create movie object
                movie = new Movie();
                movie.setId(id);
                movie.setTitle(title);
                movie.setUrlThumbnail("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + urlThumbnail);
                movie.setReleaseDate(releaseDate);
                movie.setOverview(synopsis);
                movie.setRating(rating);
                movie.setPopularity(popularity);
                movie.setVoteCount(votecount);
                //This decides when to add movies to the ArrayList
                if (id != -1 && !title.equals(Constants.NA)) {
                    listMovie.add(movie);
                    sortListRating.add(movie);

                }

            }

        }
        Collections.sort(sortListRating);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());

    }

}

public String getRequestUrl() {
    //SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    //String order = pref.getString(getString(R.string.pref_order_key), getString(R.string.pref_popularity));

    //if(order.equals(getString(R.string.pref_rating)))
    //  return URL + "vote_average" + UrlEndpoints.URL_PARAM + MyApplication.API_KEY;
    //else
    return URL + "popularity" + UrlEndpoints.URL_PARAM + MyApplication.API_KEY;

}

//Base Adapter which is used to put poster in grid view
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Movie> movieItems;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Movie> movieList) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.movieItems = movieList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return movieItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_movies, null);
        }

        mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.networkImageView);
        //Getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
        //Thumbnail Image
        //ImageLoader is used to load the images from json object retrieved.


        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String sortby = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_key), getString(R.string.pref_default_value));
        if (sortby.equals(getString(R.string.pref_rating))) {
            imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(m.getUrlThumbnail(), imageLoader);
        } else if (!sortby.equals(getString(R.string.pref_rating))) {
            imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(m.getUrlThumbnail(), imageLoader);

        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
    // Added preferences from XML
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);


    // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
    // updated when the preference changes.
    // Added preferences
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key)));
}

/**
 * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
 * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
 * is changed.)
 */
private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
    String stringValue = value.toString();

    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
        // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    } else {
        // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am storing data in ArrayList on the basis of popularity of movie and then sorting the same array list on the basis of rating and storing in new ArrayList.How to refresh data when preference is changed?

Comment: Update your list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

When you resume your activity, the adapter should be notified that the underlying data has changed. You should use:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I should use it inside onResume().

Comment: It doesn't matter, but if you use the same instance of the activty, then you want to call it when it resumed .

Comment: It is not refreshed automatically.I have tap on the grid view of any movie then when I comeback to main activity it refreshes.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using after changing the prefrence? I mean the part when you're going back to the activity containing the ListView

Comment: Did you write it's working and then edited it or do I lose my mind? :)

Comment: What i want is when I change the preference in setting i.e. sort by rating or sort by popularity , it should automatically refresh main activity depending on preferences.

Comment: I understand it, but the way you refresh it depends on how you get back to the activity. If you create a new activity it doesn't matter, but if you get back to the same activity you should check that the code for refreshing is executing (as mentioned probably onResume is a good place)

Comment: But u know after I change the preference and go to main activity, it does not show any change but when i open the detail view i.e. detail activity of that it refreshes then.

Comment: Where in your activity code did you put mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
        sendJsonRequest();
    }

    
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: Try debugging it and see if that line is executing

Comment: Yes, the statement is executing.

Comment: It looks like you should refresh mFinalAdapter, because you're using it.

Comment: Where do you actually change the adapter's data after the user changed his prefrence?

Comment: inside initialAdapter() method.

Comment: So when the activity resumes you actually don't change the data. You should update the data before calling notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: data is changed on what user selects. I have two array list i.e. listMovies and sortListRating. First arraylist is assigned to adapter when user chooses sort by popularity and second arraylist is assigned to adapter when user chooses sort by rating.

Comment: Yes, but initializeAdapter is called  in onCreate. When you're resuming your activity it won't be called again. So either create a new adapter or update the data of the current adapter